# How to run UWP app on Simulator and simulate a location?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I need to test my UWP application using a simulated location.

I assume that I can do this by running the app on the simulator instead of the local machine, but there is a problem. When I select Simulator, the simulator opens but never finished initializing. It is stuck in a state with a series of dots running across the screen.

In the Visual Studio window, the last message I see is "Registering the application to run from layout". I don't know what that means.

I found some old posts that suggest I need to acquire or renew a license. I checked to make sure that Developer Mode was enabled on my machine and I also ran "Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense" from an elevated PowerShell account, but it did not fix the problem.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: I see two different questions here. But SO rules says: One question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I start a UWP simulator?

Your system need to support **Hardware-assisted virtualization** and

[image]

**Enable Hyper-v for emulator**

[image]

Then switch the **Solution Platforms** to X86 or x64.

[image]

For more info please refer [**Run Windows Store apps in the simulator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-in-the-simulator?view=vs-2015)

### simulate a location?

> The Visual Studio 2015 simulator does not include the geolocation button. This is because the Windows 10 simulator does not include geolocation simulation. If you need to do this kind of simulation, you can use the Visual Studio 2013 simulator on Windows 8.1 or earlier operating systems.

Comment: Location: I always use abstractions for such kind of data (f.i. IGeoLocationProvider) and now every part will be testable and fakeable

Comment: Thanks for the information. My system does not appear to support virtualization, which is probably because it is itself a virtual machine. In any case, if the simulator won't simulate a location, it isn't helpful to me in this case, since what I need to test is how well my app responds to location changes while minimized. Thanks for the help.